# how to call a function on page refresh in react-redux?

Tags: api, reactjs, redux

Iam doing an app in react-redux and i want to hold my redux store on page refresh and thought to not make use of predefined libraries and hence i set the redux state to local state and making the api call in `componentWillUnmount` to restore redux state on page refresh.But i couldnt do that. Is their any approch to acheive this:

And my code is:

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({
        activeUser:this.props.activeUser
    })
}
componentWillUnmount(){
    this.props.loginUser(this.state.activeUser.user);
}
```

activeUser is my redux state and `this.props.loginUser()` makes api call.And i tried of using event handlers as:

```
componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', this.saveStore)
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.saveStore)
}

saveStore(){
    this.props.loginUser(this.state.activeUser.user);
}
```

but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: I don't think you can preserve the state upon refresh. You either need to use local/session storage to store state OR write your state into json file and restore it from there, and restore it back once refresh is done

Comment: what you need to do is save the store in localStorage and load it when your page is opened again. That you can do in your main App

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that what you basically are trying to do is that, you want to persist your app state (**user** info, etc) between reloads.

One can use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) API to achieve this effect.

I'll give one possible solution down here.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {activeUser: null};
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let activeUser = localStrorage.getItem("activeUser");
    if (activeUser) {
      this.props.receivedActiveUser(JSON.parse(activeUser));
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({activeUser: nextProps.activeUser});
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    if (this.state.activeUser) {
      localStorage.setItem("activeUser", JSON.stringify(this.state.activeUser));
    }
  }
}
```

Ofcourse, you'll have to create a `receivedActiveUser` action which will update the store appropriately.